# Enhance a multidimensional sparse array data structure

Tags: multidimensional-array, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I need an efficient data structure to store a multidimensional sparse array.

There are only 2 operations over the array:

- batch insert of values, usually of a larger number of new values that existed in the array before. Very unlikely that there is a key collision on insert, however if it happens then the value is not updated.
- query values in certain range (e.g. read range from index `[2, 3, 10, 2]` to `[2, 3, 17, 6]` in order)

From the start I know number of dimensions (usually between 3 to 10) and their sizes (each index can be stored in `Int64` and product of all sizes doesn't exceed 2^256) and the upper limit on possible number of the array cells (usually 2^26-2^32).

Currently I use a balanced binary tree for storing the sparse array, the `UInt256` key is formed as usual:
`key  = (...(index_0 * dim_size_1 + index_1) + ... + index_n-1) * dim_size_n + index_n`
with operation time complexities (and I understand it can't be any better):

- insert in `O(log N)`
- search in `O(log N)`

Current implementation has problems:

- expensive encoding of an index tuple into the key and a key back into the indexes
- lack of locality of reference which would be beneficial during range queries

Is it a good idea to replace my tree with a skip list for the locality of reference?
When is it better to have a recursive (nested) structure of sparse arrays for each dimension instead of a single array with the composite key if the array sparseness is given?
I'm interested in any examples of efficient in-memory multidimensional array implementations and in specialized literature on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how sparse your matrix is. It's hard to give give numbers, but if it is "very" sparse then you may want to try using a PH-Tree (disclaimer: self advertisement). It is essentially a multidimensional radix-tree.

It natively supports 64bit integers ([Java](http://phtree.org) and [C++](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree-cpp)). It is not balanced but depth is inherently limited to the number of bits per dimension (usually 64). It is natively a "map", i.e. it allows only one value per coordinate (there is also a multimap version that allows multiple values). The C++ version is limited to 62 dimensions.

Operations are in the order of `O(log N)` but should be significantly faster than a (balanced) binary tree.

Please note that the C++ version doesn't compile with MSVC at the moment but there is a patch coming. Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Have you used it in production?

Comment: The C++ version was originally developed for a company that I worked for. I have improved it since then but not used it in production myself.

Comment: if that means anything, it has about 300 unit test and 24 benchmarks scenarios (each with usually 2x4 different datasets).
It has been developed for clang/gcc with bazel on linux though, so I am still catching up on support for cmake and MSVC. Also, most test/benchmark use or 3D/6D data, other dimensions have been tested less thoroughly.